# Script removing text - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

The final outcome I want to have is "Todays Beer Style is: "Beer Style". When I enter the javascript code, the "Todays Beer Style is:" disappears. I am not sure why. Below is the code.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- The Homebrewery
    Author: Chris Stastny
    Date: October 27th, 2015
-->

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The Homebrewery - Homebrewing</title>
<meta name="description" content="The Homebrewery - Homebrewing">
<meta name="author" content="Chris Stastny">
<link href="final.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
<script src="beerStyle.js"></script>

</head>
<header>
 <h1> The Homebrewery</h1>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Equipment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Brew Log</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
<body>
  <h2>Greetings!</h2>

<div id="dateBox">
    Today Beer Style is: 
    <script>
 document.getElementById("dateBox").innerHTML=style[new Date().getUTCDate()];
    </script> 
</div>   
<br>   
<img src="beer.jpg" alt="beer">

<p>This website was built to keep people informed about my homebrewing adventures. It will have brewday pictures, videos (possibly) in the future, recipes and general homebrewing information. There is also a newsletter that you can sign up for that will go into more detail about what is going on with my brewing.</p>

<br>
<footer>The Homebrewery - Homebrewing - 2015</footer>  

</body> 


</html>
```

Comment: you are changing the innerHTML of the `dateBox` which contains "Today Beer Style is"

Comment: You're overwriting everything that's inside `#dateBox` with `innerHTML`. That's as expected.

Comment: Ok. I never used innerHTML. is there anything I can do or change so "Today Beer Style is" doesn't disappear.

Comment: Also, it's a bit weird that your `header` and `nav` are in the `head`, instead of at the top of the `body`. If that's not intentional, you'll want to move them.

Answer (score 4):

When you do this:

```
document.getElementById("dateBox").innerHTML=style[new Date().getUTCDate()];
```

You are replacing everything inside that div with what you are trying to add

try:

```
document.getElementById("dateBox").innerHTML += style[new Date().getUTCDate()];
```

Comment: It's also not a good idea to have the script inside the `<div>`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<div id="dateBox">
    Today Beer Style is: 
    <script>
 document.getElementById("dateBox").innerHTML=style[new Date().getUTCDate()];
    </script> 
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="dateBox">
    Today Beer Style is: <span id="beerStyle"></span>
    <script>
 document.getElementById("beerStyle").innerHTML=style[new Date().getUTCDate()];
    </script> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the entire `div`, including the preamble. Better to have a `span` that's *just* the replaceable text:

```
 Today Beer Style is:  <span id="beerStyle"></span>
```

then

```
 document.getElementById("beerStyle").innerHTML=style[new Date().getUTCDate()];
```